# Scala's simple-build-tool doesn't appear to run tests

Tags: scala, sbt

I've used sbt to create a project, configured it thusly:

```
val scalatest = "org.scala-tools.testing" % "scalatest" % "0.9.5" % "test"
```

I then pasted the example from [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/) into a file and ran "sbt test" to see if it was working. The file compiles, but the test is never executed.

As far as I can tell, this is as simple as it's meant to be. Am I missing something?

Comment: Just to make sure, did you place the test file in the Maven-correct path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first off, I believe 1.0 is the correct version according to their website. My `project/build/def.scala` looks like this:

```
import sbt._

class Tests(info: ProjectInfo) extends DefaultProject(info) {
  val scalatest = "org.scalatest" % "scalatest" % "1.0" % "test"
}
```

Then do a `sbt update`, then a `sbt reload` (not sure the reload is necessary, but it doesn't hurt)

Now in `/src/test/scala`, use their example but also import `scala.collection.mutable.Stack`
and `sbt test` works fine for me

```
jcdavis@seam-carver:~/dev/test2$ sbt test
[info] Building project test 1.0 using Tests
[info]    with sbt 0.5.6 and Scala 2.7.7
[info] 
[info] == compile ==
[info]   Source analysis: 0 new/modified, 0 indirectly invalidated, 0 removed.
[info] Compiling main sources...
[info] Nothing to compile.
[info]   Post-analysis: 0 classes.
[info] == compile ==
[info] 
[info] == copy-test-resources ==
[info] == copy-test-resources ==
[info] 
[info] == copy-resources ==
[info] == copy-resources ==
[info] 
[info] == test-compile ==
[info]   Source analysis: 0 new/modified, 0 indirectly invalidated, 0 removed.
[info] Compiling test sources...
[info] Nothing to compile.
[info]   Post-analysis: 4 classes.
[info] == test-compile ==
[info] 
[info] == test-start ==
[info] == test-start ==
[info] 
[info] == StackSpec ==
[info] A Stack
[info] Test Starting - A Stack should pop values in last-in-first-out order
[info] Test Succeeded - A Stack should pop values in last-in-first-out order
[info] Test Starting - A Stack should throw NoSuchElementException if an empty stack is popped
[info] Test Succeeded - A Stack should throw NoSuchElementException if an empty stack is popped
[info] == StackSpec ==
[info] 
[info] == test-complete ==
[info] == test-complete ==
[info] 
[info] == test-finish ==
[info] Run: 2, Passed: 2, Errors: 0, Failed: 0
[info]  
[info] All tests PASSED.
[info] == test-finish ==
[info] 
[info] == test-cleanup ==
[info] == test-cleanup ==
[info] 
[info] == test ==
[info] == test ==
[success] Successful.
```